# add current Auth user posts to a Laravel eloquent join query

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

I have this method working but have no idea how to add `$user` posts to this query:

```
public function getFeed()
{
    $user = $this;
    return Post::join('follows', function ($join) use ($user) {
        $join->on('posts.timeline_type', '=', 'follows.followable_type')
            ->on('posts.timeline_id', '=', 'follows.followable_id')
            ->where('follows.user_id', '=', $user->id);
    })->select('posts.*')->latest()->paginate();
}
```

`$user` is the auth user

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used [Laravel Unions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#unions)

```
public function getFeed()
{
    return Post::join('follows', function ($join) {
        $join->on('posts.timeline_type', 'follows.followable_type')
            ->on('posts.timeline_id', 'follows.followable_id')
            ->whereNull('follows.deleted_at')
            ->where('follows.user_id', $this->id);
    })->select('posts.*')
    ->union($this->timeline()) // $this->timeline() is query that retrieves user timeline
    ->latest()
    ->paginate();
}
```

Comment: If you guys think there are better more performant ways, please let us know.